# nf_conntrack_ftp module has disappearedl

Tags: iptables, ftp, linode, kernel-modules, nf-conntrack

I've been running a Linode droplet for several years with no problems.  In the last month, users have reported FTP connection errors, always related to Passive FTP.

Investigation shows that the nf_conntrack_ftp module is no longer loaded. We use this module to allow iptables to properly handle passive ftp connections.

Apparently this module has vanished from the system!  modprobe nf_conntrack_ftp yields "FATAL: Module nf_conntrack_ftp not found."

I have rebooted the linode and retried.

I'm not sure what to do at this point.  Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: https://www.linode.com/docs/tools-reference/custom-kernels-distros/run-a-distribution-supplied-kernel-with-kvm

Comment: Are you saying it's not running the same kernel as before? Why would it change?

Comment: Your Linode was migrated from Xen to KVM, maybe? Or Linode decided to change what modules are available in its custom kernel?